# Laravel one to many relationship results

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i am trying to create one to many relationship. One user from user table could have many companies, on other side company could have only one user.

my migration for company table is

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->string('contact_person');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('industry');
            $table->string('website');
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my user model is

```
  /**
     * Get the posts for the user.
     */
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Company','user_id');
    }
```

my company model is

```
   public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id');
    }
```

i am trying to get all companies for specific user

try with whereHas but no data in relation object

```
      $results = Company::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
         $query->where('users.id',1);
       })->get();
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should change is `companies()` relation. It has to be `hasMany`, not `hasOne`:

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Company');
}
```

Then get user with all his companies:

```
$result = User::where('id', $id)->with('companies')->first();
```

Or, if you want to use `Company` model like in your example and get only companies:

```
$result = Company::where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

Also, you're using `id_user` in migration. Change it to `user_id`.